# Storing form information from Wordpress to a database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, crud, buddypress

I have a website where people sign up and input information about their athletic profile (bench press, hand size etc...). I also have a database connected to the wordpress website through Cpanel / PHPmyadmin and I want to store the information that the user submits via forms into that database.

I have the buddypress plugin installed and using buddypress the users sign up but from this point I am unsure where to go.

So basically the user enters their information and registers on the website using a buddypress form and with that information I want to store that data into my database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress / Buddypress is a database driven application. All the information that persists in Wordpress *is* in the database.

The specific feature you're looking for are xProfile fields. [This article explains how to add them](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/modifying-the-registration-form/) (No programming required), while [this one explains how to display that data](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/displaying-extended-profile-fields-on-member-profiles/) (Programming required).

Comment: So I took a look at my database for the one I set up for my wordpress and all the tables got created automatically...dammit. good to know though